# Convert exponentials and rounding numbers in BASH

Tags: bash, awk

i have such a file

```
1.5000000000E-01 7.5714285714E+00 4.0000000000E-01
2.5000000000E-01 7.5714285714E+00 4.0000000000E-01
```

and i have to convert it to something like

```
0.15 7.57 0.40
```

i mean i want the numbers to be with only 2 decimals and not to be exponential. I want to use bash!

Comment: Bash doesn't do decimals.

Answer (score 6):

Using `printf` with `awk`:

```
$ awk '{printf "%.2f %.2f %.2f\n",$1,$2,$3}' file
0.15 7.57 0.40
0.25 7.57 0.40
```

Given more fields you would want to loop like:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "%.2f ",$i;print "\n"}' file
0.15 7.57 0.40
0.25 7.57 0.40
```

Comment: awk to the rescue once more. +1

Answer (score 4):

This can work:

```
printf "%1.2f" $number
```

Test:

```
$ for i in 1.5000000000E-01 7.5714285714E+00 4.0000000000E-01 2.5000000000E-01 7.5714285714E+00 4.0000000000E-01;
do
   printf "%1.2f\n" $i
done
0.15
7.57
0.40
0.25
7.57
0.40
```

In your case,

```
cat file | xargs printf "%1.2f\n"
```

Test:

```
$ cat file | xargs printf "%1.2f\n"
0.15
7.57
0.40
0.25
7.57
0.40
```

Comment: This doesn't demonstrate how to read the input from the file and the original format of the file is lost.

Comment: We are not concatenating any files here so throw away the UUoC `xargs printf "%1.2f\n" < file` but this still destroys the file format. The best I came up with using `xargs` and `printf` is `xargs printf "%1.2f " < ~/file | xargs -n3
` but it's not great :/

Comment: why use echo/xargs in this case and not `printf "%1.2f\n" $i` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat numbers.txt
1.5000000000E-01 7.5714285714E+00 4.0000000000E-01
2.5000000000E-01 7.5714285714E+00 4.0000000000E-01

$ while read F1 F2 F3;do printf "%.2f %.2f %.2f\n" $F1 $F2 $F3;done < numbers.txt
0.15 7.57 0.40
0.25 7.57 0.40
```