# Converting exponents to integers in Bash

Tags: bash, integer, exponent

I want to convert some timestamps in a text file from exponents to integers. The problem is that in the file there are already columns that are decimal numbers and those I don't want to change. I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16686819/convert-exponentials-and-rounding-numbers-in-bash) where the OP has a very similar problem and I came up with this code:

```
awk '{printf "%13.0f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%10.0f",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6; print 

"\n"} foo.csv
```

However, the code converts my timestamp just fine, but then converts all the other numbers to 0, like so:

```
`1391470000000,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0000000000
 1391380000000,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0000000000`
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

My input numbers, foo.csv:

```
1.39147e+12,56.32,57.88,56.09,57.81,2911900000
1.39138e+12,58.15,58.48,56.08,56.15,2929300000
```

Comment: Please give your input numbers for example.

Comment: Can you give a line from the csv file as an example input?

Comment: You should include the newline in the `printf` format string, rather than adding a second print statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't set the input field separator to a comma so the whole record is read as a single string, and the `%13.0f` format is converting just the first part (up to the first comma). The rest of the fields (2 through 6) are empty, and therefore equal 0. Try:

```
awk -F, '{printf "%13.0f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f,%10.0f\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6} foo.csv
```

Or perhaps:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{$1 = sprintf("%13.0f", $1); print}' foo.csv
```